# Is it ok to have a class with just properties?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a method that is over 700+ lines long.  In the beginning of the method, there are around 50 local variables declared.  I decided to take the local variables out and put them into a separate class as properties so I could just declare the class in the method and use the properties through out it.  Is this perfectly fine or does another data type fit in here such as a struct?  This method was written during classic ASP times.

Comment: It's potentially okay, or potentially horrible. Please provide some example code.

Comment: Rather than one class where all vars are stored, you'd probably fare better dividing the variables into several logically relevant and coherent classes/structs. That way you'll gain also insight into how to extract parts of that 700+ lines method into smaller, common functions.

Comment: @Elideb, good point, I was thinking that, but I first decided to move them to one class. Then I was extract the relevant variables into their own classes/structs as you said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have a method that is over 700+ lines long. In the beginning of the method, there are around 50 local variables declared.

Ok, so, the length of that method is also a problem.  700 lines is just too much to keep straight in one normal person's head all at once.  When you have to fix a bug in there you end up scrolling up and down and up and down and... you get the idea.  It really makes things hard to maintain.

So my answer is, yes, you should likely split up your data into a structure of some sort assuming that it actually makes sense to do so (i.e., I probably wouldn't create a `SomeMethodParmaters` class).  The next thing to do is to split that method out into smaller pieces.  You may even find that you no longer need a data structure as now each method only has a handful of variables declared for the work it needs to do.

Also, this is subjective, but there is really no good reason to declare all variables at the top of the method.  Try declaring them as close to when they are actually used as possible.  Again, this just keeps things nice and clean for maintenance in the future.  It's much easier to concentrate on one section of code when you can see it all on the screen.

Comment: Good points also. All of them I have thought about.  The problems I face is that it is 700+ lines long.  The original developer left no comments and the variable names are not very descriptive.

Answer (score 8):

Hrm... I think you'd probably be better off refactoring the method to not have to operate on so many variables at all.  For instance, five methods operating on ten variables each would infinitely better. As it stands now, it *feels* like you're simply trying to mask an issue rather than solve it.

Comment: I agree with you. I am trying to refactor it by not having so many variables, but I am taking minor steps

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you take a read through this book and/or any number of web sites concerned with refactoring.  [http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)

Although you can't look at 700+ lines in a single method and automatically say that is bad, it does indicate a bad code smell.  Methods should be small units of code with a single purpose.  This makes it easier for you to maintain or those who come behind you.  It can also help you to figure out improvements to your design and make altering your design in the future much easier.

Creating a class just to hold properties without looking at what the overall structure should be is just hiding a problem.  That is not to say in this particular instance that is not a perfectly acceptable and correct solution, just that you should make sure you are taking the time to provide a properly thought out design where your classes have the properties, state, and functionality they deserve.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the book. My end result is not to have a class with just variables, I just wanted to get the 50+ variables out of the 700+ line method so I can start breaking it it up into smaller manageable methods.